# Limit involving functions

Tags: limits, functions

I was solving problems on limits until I found this problem which completely stumped me .

If $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\left(f(x+1) + \frac{5}{f(x+2)}\right)$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ belonging to real numbers,then what is     $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) 
$$

I have no idea where to begin with . I tried to find functional values but that wasn't of much use . Could you suggest a working logic , that might work for problems of these kinds ?

EDIT : How do I know if the limit exists in the first place ? It isn't necessary for it to converge , right ? Isn't it necessary to check for the existence before actually finding out its value ? Because if it doesn't even exist , then all of the calculations are null and void .

Comment: Strongly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2144732 (where the value of the limit is determined, without proving its existence).

Comment: If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists, then use the fact that $$lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x+1)=lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x+2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function converges: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x+1)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x+2)=:F$
Now, taking the limit of both sides:
$$F=\frac{1}{3}\bigg(F+\frac{5}{F}\bigg)$$
$$3F^2=F^2+5$$
$$2F^2=5$$
$$F^2=\frac{5}{2}$$
$$F=\pm \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$$
From $f(x)>0$ we can see that $F>0$, so the limit is positive:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$$

Comment: Refer martin's comment and linked answer. This does not show existence. Well if OP prefers this then its duplicate question.

Comment: This is okay , but how do I know if the limit even exists in the first place ? What if it just doesn't converge ?

Comment: @Tanuj To be honest, I'm not sure if the convergence of the function is ascertainable from that amount of information. But if it converges, it's limit is the calculated one. If it doesn't, then it is $\infty$. But I'd like to hear the opinion of a smarter person on it.

Comment: Anyways , thanks for your time and help man ! And me too !

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\left(f(x+1) + \frac{5}{f(x+2)}\right)$$
$$\implies \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(f(x+1) + \frac{5}{f(x+2)}\right)$$

As $x\rightarrow\infty$, so do, $x+1$ and $x+2$. So, they all tend to a common value. So,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x+1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x+2)=t(say)$$

$$t=\frac{1}{3}\left(t + \frac{5}{t}\right)$$
$$\implies t=\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \quad \because \ t>0$$